# Application logging in Azure Kubernetes

Tags: azure, nlog, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics

In our scenario, we are trying to Dockerize the Asp.net framework 4.6 based Web API that logs on the server using Nlog.

Currently the application is hosted on IIS web server.

**The question is how / where to store the logs when the application is rehosted on Azure kubernetes**

**should I use something like application insights**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Monitor for Containers is perfect for Infrastructure monitoring and Application Insights which is now part of Monitor as well would be excellent for APM.

Application Insights for .NET
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Azure Monitor including Application Insights to have your application logs.

Here is the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/cloud-native/monitoring-azure-kubernetes) on Azure Monitor for containers

> Azure Monitor for Containers supports consuming logs from not just
> Kubernetes but also from other orchestration engines such as DC/OS,
> Docker Swarm, and Red Hat OpenShift.